# ARKit - How to rotate the object by swiping?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I use ARKit plugin for Unity in order to place a 3D object on the real world surface. After placing an object, how can I rotate it by swiping my finger over it on the iPhone screen?

Comment: Could you show us what you've done so far? 
Generally you should should save a reference to the object you want to rotate, add a swipe gesture recognizer with a target function, and then use the rotateBy function to apply this rotation on the axis that you want to rotate your object on.